# getViewById from slide in ViewPager

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with some slides. On one of those slides I want a ListView which shall be populated by an adapter.

MyPager.java

```
public class myPager extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_pager_layout);


    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDots);
    btnSkip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_skip);
    btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);

    layouts = new int[]{
            R.layout.my_slide1,
            R.layout.my_slide2,
            R.layout.my_slide3};

    //... some code...//
    ArrayList<String> routes = new ArrayList<>();
    ListView routeList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.routesList);
    ArrayAdapter routeAdaper = new RouteAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, routes);
// I get my error here
}}
```

This is the slide with the ListView. 
my_slide3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/routesList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

my_pager_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDots"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dots_height"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dots_margin_bottom"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:alpha=".5"
        android:layout_above="@id/layoutDots"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_skip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/skip"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The getViewById returns null. I assume, because the ListView is in a View which is not the ContentView. 
So what is the best practice to get that ListView and set an Adapter to it?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635687/getviewbyid-returns-null-for-the-listview) might help you.

Comment: You need to findViewById inside the pager adapter

Comment: @elmorabea that makes sense! in the instantiateItem() ?

Comment: i got it working! thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome, cheers!